# Mysql inner join with condition on joined data

Tags: mysql, join

I have the folowing tables:

Table student:

```
id  name
1   foo
2   bar
3   baz
```

Table mark

```
student_id  mark  date
1           9     2011-08-10
1           20    2011-08-09
1           5     2011-08-08
2           12    2011-08-09
2           8     2011-08-10
3           10    2011-08-10
```

I want each student with their last mark, ie

```
foo 9
bar 8
baz 10
```

How can i do that with mysql?

EDIT: The point of this example is how to add a sorting condiction on the joined table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use a `GROUP BY`and the `MAX`aggregate function to create a recordset containing all students with their latest date. This recordset can then be joined back to the original tables to retrieve the other columns needed.

[The GROUP BY Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate
>   functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

[MAX([DISTINCT] expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)

> Returns the maximum value of expr. MAX() may take a string argument;
>   in such cases, it returns the maximum string value.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  s.name
        , m.Mark
FROM    student s
        INNER JOIN mark m ON m.student_id = s.id
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  s.id,
                  MAX(m.Date) as MaxDate
          FROM    student s
                  INNER JOIN mark m ON m.student_id = s.id
          GROUP BY
                  s.id
        ) sm ON sm.id = m.student_id AND sm.MaxDate = m.date
```

Comment: @pinouchon - I have edited the original answer to include your new requirements.